# android R.java drawable class doesnt updated after add pictures to drawable folder

Tags: java, android, cordova, r.java-file

I'm using Android studio and my project is cordova with android platform:

I added a new pictures to my app -> res-> drawable folder but when I try to run the following code line:

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.win)
```

When I write R.drawable. it gives me the option to select "win".

But at run time I get the following  error:

```
cannot find symbol variable win
```

In addition I checked the file R.java and I actually see that it is not updating the drawable class to contain the new pictures(win.png)

I try to do:

1. Clean and rebuild the project
2. Restart Android studion
3. Delete R.java
4. Look in XML files, for making sure that there is no error

Nothing helps...what else can I do?

p.s

I just do as the following link recomended:

1)Go to your image in windows, then press ctrl + c OR Right click and Copy

2)Go to Your res Folder And choose One of the folders(eg. MDPI, HDPI..) and press ctrl + v OR right click it and Paste

Do I need to do more than copy paste?

Comment: check your import statement for R in that class

Comment: thats my imort: import com.example.pg.R; what may be the problem with the import?

Comment: can you post the code where you setting drawable

Comment: I just do as the following link recomended: Go to your image in windows, then press ctrl + c OR Right click and Copy

Go to Your res Folder And choose One of the folders(eg. MDPI, HDPI..) and press ctrl + v OR right click it and Paste